# Is it normal to have to log in twice to 'see all inbox items'?

Tags: support

When I am logged into my account and then click on the inbox icon, I see a list of recent messages in a drop down window. After scrolling to the bottom, I have the option to 'see all inbox items'.

When I click it, why am I sent to a different log in page? Is it normal to have to log in twice to 'see all inbox items'?

Comment: The link takes you to inbox on your network-wide SE profile. While this should be usually transparent, it wouldn't suprise me if it *occasionally* led to a re-login (e.g., if you haven't visited the network profile for a while). Even on MO itself, the system may spontaneously require a new login from time to time.